# Determine Position (lan-long) on turning radius from a point to another point

Tags: math, geolocation, trigonometry

[image: sketch]

Lat-lon position `A` and `B` are known, the turning radius `r` also known.

I need help to create a function to calculate position 'P' for any turning "progress" (0.0 - 1.0) between position `A` and `B`

- progress 0.0 = A
- progress 1.0 = B
- progress x = P

```cpp
LatLon getTurnInterpolation(LatLon A, LatLon B, double r, double progress){
}
```

since there are two possible option for position C, we can just assume the turning is always anti-clockwise from A to B, also the position is in spherical space (WGS84 lat-lon) or all distance are great circle distance

Comment: isn't just use % of degree enough? what you want else?

Comment: the problem is C is unknown, and point is in lat-lon coordinate (not simple x-y cartesian), so line from A to B actually curved line along earth surface

Comment: @‌uray isn't lat-lon just make it eaiser? since it's already in angle.

Comment: dont get it wrong, C is not center of earth, A,B,C,P are point on earth/spherical surface

Comment: OK I see, C is on surface.

Comment: so you calculate C then do the remain math.